# Q: Limits Definition

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove using the limits definition that if $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}f(h)=A$ then $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}f(h^2)=A$. Is the opposite true?

The limits definitions really confuse me and I am hoping I can learn them better through this simple excercise

Comment: In my understand this is a theoritical question. As I edited right after I posted this the limits definitions confuse me a lot and I don't see me solving this alone.

Comment: depending on the progress of your lecture: starting with definition or using that $h\mapsto h^2$ is continuous.

Comment: You will have to start with the definition of "limit". Here's an easier question you might want to try first: can you prove the claim when you have $2h$ instead of $h*2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\,f(h)=A\tag{1}
$$
means that for any $\epsilon\gt0$, there is a $\delta\gt0$ so that for all $0\lt|h|\le\delta$, we have $|f(h)-A|\le\epsilon$.

Thus, if $|h|\le\sqrt\delta$, then $h^2\le\delta$, so we have $|\,f\!\left(h^2\right)-A|\le\epsilon$. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\,f\!\left(h^2\right)=A\tag{2}
$$
However, suppose we only have $(2)$, then we only know the behavior of $f(x)$ for $x\ge0$ since $h^2\ge0$; therefore, we do not know the behavior for $x\lt0$. Thus, we cannot assert $(1)$ since that requires knowledge of $f(x)$ for $x\lt0$.

---

Consider the function
$$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}
\sgn(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
+1&\text{if }x\gt0\\
0&\text{if }x=0\\
-1&\text{if }x\lt0
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}
$$
We have that
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\sgn\left(h^2\right)=1\tag{4}
$$
However
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\sgn(h)\tag{5}
$$
does not exist.

---

Summarizing,
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\,f(h)=A\implies\lim_{h\to0}\,f\!\left(h^2\right)=A\tag{6}
$$
but the converse is not necessarily true.

Comment: wow, thanks for taking the time to make a such well organised post. You have really helped me understand the definition and you answered well to my question

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped. Understanding the basics is very important for further study. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

the limit as $h$ goes to zero of $f(h)=A$ means that

for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that

$|f(h)-A| \lt \epsilon$ for all $|h-0|=|h| \lt \delta$

If limit as $h$ went to zero of $f(h^2)=A$ this would imply that for any $\epsilon  \gt 0$ , there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $|f(h^2)-A| \lt \epsilon$ for all $|h| \lt \delta$

equivalent for all $h^2 \lt \delta^{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Picture a function $f(x)$ that is well behaved for positive values of $x$ but does all kinds of crazy things for negative values.  Because $h^2$ is always positive for nonzero values of $h$, the limit $\lim_{h\to0}f(h^2)$ will only see the well-behaved side, whereas $\lim_{h\to0}f(h)$ sees both.  So no, $\lim_{h\to0}f(h^2)=A$ does not imply $\lim_{h\to0}f(h)=A$, because the latter limit may not exist even though the former does.